# Unable to find an exact match for CDP version 98, so returning the closest version found: 97

Tags: selenium

[this is the screenshot of my first test case in selenium](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQEZv.png)

pls help me with this what error its there as I am new to selenium

Answer (score 0):

Try using something like this:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'COMPOSE')]")));

// click on the compose button as soon as the "compose" button is visible
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'COMPOSE')]")).click();
}
```

Source: https://www.browserstack.com/guide/wait-commands-in-selenium-webdriver

Your error is caused by trying to Click on something that the webdriver has not found, giving it time to load the webpage will help.